# Is $l^2 \cong l^2 \otimes l^2 \cong l^2 \oplus l^2$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

I'm trying to learn about tensor products of Hilbert spaces and started to wonder if $l^2 \cong l^2 \otimes l^2 \cong l^2 \oplus l^2$?

If $(e_n)$ denotes the standard basis, in the first case, it seems like I can make an isomorphism by mapping the basis elements "diagonally":
$$e_1 \mapsto e_1 \otimes e_1$$
$$e_1 \mapsto e_1 \otimes e_2$$
$$e_3 \mapsto e_2 \otimes e_1$$
etc.
and similarly for the second case
$$e_1 \mapsto (e_1, 0)$$
$$e_2 \mapsto (0, e_1)$$
$$e_3 \mapsto (e_2, 0)$$
etc.

Comment: Since all spaces you list are separable Hilbert spaces, they are trivially isometrically isomorphic. However, the tensor product of $\ell^2(I)$ with itself is more naturally identified with $\ell^2(I^2)$, while the sum is naturally isomorphic to $\ell^2$ on two copies of $I$.